# Android Soft Keyboard Auto Capitalise without EditText

Tags: java, android, input, android-softkeyboard

I'm managing the `Android Soft Keyboard` manually (have no `EditText`, shown and dismissed using `InputMethodManager`). Is there a way to turn auto capitalise on for words/sentences in the Soft Keyboard? All other questions/answers seem to have `EditText` involved.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without Edittext, why need to capitalise the soft keyboard ?

Comment: I've got a listener setup for when keys are pressed which I respond to. I want to show the keyboard capitalised so that when the user is entering some text, they know the text will start capitalised.